Preserving spatial distribution of data during data splitting
I am trying to model nitrate concentrations in the streams in Bavaria in Germany using Random Forest model. I am using Python and primarily sklearn for the same. I have data from 490 water quality stations. I am following the methodology in the paper from LongzhuQ.Shen et al which can be found here: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41597-020-0478-7
I want to split my dataset into training and testing set such that the spatial distribution of data in both sets is identical. The idea is that if data splitting ignores the spatial distribution, there is a risk that the training set might end up with a concentration of points from densely populated areas, leaving out sparser areas. This can skew the model's learning process, making it less accurate or generalizable across the entire area of interest. sklearn train_test_split just randomly divides the data into training and testing sets and it does not consider the spatial patterns in the data.
The paper I mentioned above follows this methodology: "We split the full dataset into two sub-datasets, training and testing respectively. To consider the heterogeneity of the spatial distribution of the gauge stations, we employed the spatial density estimation technique in the data splitting step by building a density surface using Gaussian kernels with a bandwidth of 50 km (using v.kernel available in GRASS GIS33) for each species and season. The pixel values of the resultant density surface were used as weighting factors to split the data into training and testing subsets that possess identical spatial distributions."
I want to follow the same methodology but instead of using grass GIS, I am just building the density surface myself in Python. I have also extracted the probability density values and the weights for the stations. (attached figure)
Now the only problem I am facing is how do I use these weights to split the data into training and testing sets? I checked there is no keyword in the sklearn train_test_split function that can consider the weights. I also went back and forth with chat GPT 4 but it is also not able to give me a clear answer. Neither did I find anything concrete on the internet about this. Maybe I am missing something.
Is there any other function I can use to do this? Or will I have to write my own algorithm to do the splitting? In case of the latter, can you please suggest me the approach so I can code it myself?
In the attached figure you can see the location of the stations and the probability density surface generated using the kernel density estimation method (using Gaussian kernels).
Also attaching a screenshot of my dataframe to give you some idea of the data structure. (all columns after longitude ('lon') column are used as features. the NO3 column is used as the target variable.)
Please find the attached images for reference.
Probability density surface generated using the kernel density estimation method with gaussian kernels.
the dataset I am using to model the nitrate concentrations

This seems to work as required. It checks out visually, at least. You'd need to explore the results further to confirm they're correct and as expected. I think the distributions of various parameters (e.g. df.hist()) ought to look similar between the sampled and remainder sets.
The process I followed sounds similar to the one you quoted, where I use the "pixel values" (KDE score for each data point) as "weighting factors".
I fitted a KernelDensity estimator in order to derive a density score for each data point, and then supplied the density scores to the weights= parameter of <dataframe>.resample(...).
Visual comparison below between unweighted and weighted sampling results.
Sampling without weights:

Sampling with weights:


Reproducible example:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#
#Data for testing
#
np.random.seed(0)
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons

X, _ = make_moons(n_samples=400, noise=0.1, random_state=11)
X = np.concatenate([X, np.random.uniform(-2, 2, size=[500, 2])], axis=0)

#Adjust scale and location
X[:, 0] = (X[:, 0] - X[:, 0].min()) / (X[:, 0] - X[:, 0].min()).max() * 4 + 10
X[:, 1] = (X[:, 1] - X[:, 1].min()) / (X[:, 0] - X[:, 0].min()).max() * 7.5 + 47

df = pd.DataFrame({'latitude': X[:, 1], 'longitude': X[:, 0]})

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 3.5))
ax.scatter(df.longitude, df.latitude, marker='.', color='black', label='monitoring station')
ax.set(xlabel='longitude', ylabel='latitude')
ax.spines[:].set_visible(False)

#
#Fit a density estimator & get the density map
#
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

kd_estimator = KernelDensity(bandwidth=0.3, kernel='gaussian').fit(df[['longitude', 'latitude']])
density_scores = np.exp(kd_estimator.score_samples( df[['longitude', 'latitude']] ))
df['sample_weights'] = density_scores / density_scores.sum() #optionally norm to 1
 
#Overlay the density map
im = ax.tricontourf(
    df.longitude, df.latitude, density_scores,
    zorder=0, cmap='BuGn', levels=100
)
f.colorbar(im, label='density')

#Sample based on weight
df_test = df.sample(frac=0.2, weights=df.sample_weights, random_state=0)
# df_test = df.sample(frac=0.2, random_state=0) #sample without weights

df_train = df.drop(index=df_test.index)

#Visualise sampling distribution
ax.scatter(
    df_test.longitude, df_test.latitude,
    marker='o', s=50, facecolor='none', edgecolor='tab:red', linewidth=2,
    label='test sample'
)
f.legend(ncol=2)
f.tight_layout()


No problem. I didn't vote on it but I can check the "Close" details, which say it has been voted as "Not about programming or software development" and they link to here which provides information about that aspect.
